# library for rendering svg into css

Tags: android, css, svg, mobile-safari

Is there any library or easy solution to render SVGs using CSS (CSS3?)

With CSS you can draw things, but it's easier to do that using easy tools like Inkscape to create the svg, then convert it to CSS.
Here is an exemple of CSS logo :
[Check this link](http://ecsspert.com/play/css3-logos/twitter.php#edit)

The first use of this is rendering high quality graphics even in old browsers which supports CSS but not SVG (Android 2.2, 2.3, ..., iPhone browser, ..)
CSS graphics also have accelerated rendering more than SVG.

Answer (score 2):

There is no library to automatically convert from SVG to CSS.

There are, however, a couple of drawing libraries based on CSS + HTML. They should make the task of converting a logo to CSS easier. Examples of such libraries are:

- [jsgraphics](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm)
- [Donatello](https://github.com/dnewcome/Donatello)

Answer (score 1):

A good one I tried was http://raphaeljs.com/

Only bad thing is the documentation is a bit messy - but the library works.